# Gitlab-Runner instance stuck on "Submitting job to coordinator" after canceling a job

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab runner instance with a simple shell runner configured:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Runner - Development"
  url = (my_url)
  token = (the token)
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

But for some reason when I cancel the job manually on the pipelines page on my gitlab repository the instance/runner gets stuck and does not accept any other jobs until I restart the container:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=1 revision=7f7a4bb0 version=13.11.0
Starting multi-runner from /.gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                   
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
Checking for jobs... received                       job=506 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=22.095762662 job=506 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=507 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=293.787702009 job=507 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=510 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=17.323713912 job=510 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=511 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=276.921315586 job=511 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=513 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=401.713905535 job=513 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=512 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=21.636549273 job=512 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=514 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=17.707020252 job=514 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=515 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=270.15396228 job=515 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=516 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=232.158723491 job=516 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=518 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
Job succeeded                                       duration_s=32.016943551 job=518 project=114 runner=runner_id
Checking for jobs... received                       job=519 repo_url=(my private gitlab instance url) runner=runner_id
WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... job failed  code=202 job=519 job-log=0-3122 job-status=canceled runner=runner_id sent-log=3060-3121 status=202 Accepted update-interval=0s
WARNING: Error while executing file based variables removal script  error=context canceled job=519 project=114 runner=runner_id
WARNING: Job failed: canceled                       duration_s=9.101718877 job=519 project=114 runner=runner_id
WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... range mismatch  code=416 job=519 job-log=0-3122 job-status= runner=runner_id sent-log=3060-3200 status=416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable update-interval=0s
WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... job failed  code=202 job=519 job-log=0-3201 job-status=canceled runner=runner_id sent-log=3122-3200 status=202 Accepted update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Appending trace to coordinator... range mismatch  code=416 job=519 job-log=0-3201 job-status= runner=runner_id sent-log=3122-3200 status=416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
WARNING: Submitting job to coordinator... failed    code=400 job=519 job-status= runner=runner_id status=400 Bad Request update-interval=0s
```

I have 2 questions:

- How may I configure this runner/instance in such a way that I can avoid this problem?
- How may I configure my Dockerfile that has the gitlab runner instances to watch this kind of problems (like HEALTHCHECK) and restart the container (I am running it in a stack in docker-swarm)?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that issue?